# using a column to add shape to a plot with no fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have this plot and I would like to use the "shape" column of the dat dataframe to determine the shape of the points. 2 points should be filled in using shape = 16 and the rest are hallow using shape =1 BUT it does not seem to be working. Any thoughts?

```
  time = as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-01 00:00:01","2016-05-01 00:00:02","2016-05-01 00:00:03","2016-05-01 00:00:01","2016-05-01 00:00:02","2016-05-01 00:00:03"), tz = "GMT")
    group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
    value =c(NA, 99, 100, NA, 101, 100)
    size =c(NA, 3, 10, NA, 5, 4)
    dat =data.frame(time= time, group =group, value =value ,size =size, shape= c(1,16,16,1,1,1) )
    dat
    ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y = value, group = group )) +geom_line() +
      geom_point(aes (color = as.factor(group), size = size ), shape=shape) +
      scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M:%S", breaks= date_breaks("5 min")) # + scale_fill_manual(values=c(NA,NA)) doesnt work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass a factor to shape. You need to use scale_shape_identity to tell it to use the values passed as the actual shapes.

Borrowing heavily from Eric's answer:

```
time = as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-01 00:00:01","2016-05-01 00:00:02","2016-05-01 00:00:03","2016-05-01 00:00:01","2016-05-01 00:00:02","2016-05-01 00:00:03"), tz = "GMT")
group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
value =c(NA, 99, 100, NA, 101, 100)
size =c(NA, 3, 10, NA, 5, 4)
dat =data.frame(time= time, group =group, value =value ,size =size, shape= c(1L,16L,16L,1L,1L,1L) )
dat
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y = value, group = group )) +geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes (color = as.factor(group), size = size , shape=shape)) +
  scale_shape_identity()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your `shape` is not within aesthetic. Also, to work with shape parameter, it has to be turned into a factor.

Here is code that (should) produce what you expect to have:

```
time = as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-01 00:00:01","2016-05-01 00:00:02","2016-05-01 00:00:03","2016-05-01 00:00:01","2016-05-01 00:00:02","2016-05-01 00:00:03"), tz = "GMT")
group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
value =c(NA, 99, 100, NA, 101, 100)
size =c(NA, 3, 10, NA, 5, 4)
dat =data.frame(time= time, group =group, value =value ,size =size, shape= factor(c(1,16,16,1,1,1)) )
dat
ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y = value, group = group )) +geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes (color = as.factor(group), size = size , shape=shape))
```

Comment: That produces hollow blue circles and solid red triangles. i am looking for all circles solid and hollow.  I think 1 and 16 are both circles looking at ?pch but the shapes are coming in wrong

Comment: You don't need to pass a factor to shape. You need to use scale_shape_identity to tell it to use the values passed as the actual shapes. The help on shape states: `# Shape takes four types of values: an integer in [0, 25],
# a single character-- which uses that character as the plotting symbol,
# a . to draw the smallest rectangle that is visible (i.e., about one pixel)
# an NA to draw nothing`